# How can I read and manipulate large csv files in Google Colaboratory while not using all the RAM?

Tags: pandas, ram, large-files, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import and manipulate compressed .csv files (that are each about 500MB in compressed form) in Google Colaboratory. There are 7 files. Using pandas.read_csv(), I "use all the available RAM" just after 2 files are imported and I have to restart my runtime.

I have searched forever on here looking for answers and have tried all the ones I came across, but none work. I have the files in my google drive and am mounted to it.

How can I read all of the files and manipulate them without using all the RAM? I have 12.72GB of RAM and 358.27GM of Disk.

Buying more RAM isn't an option.

Comment: Have you considered buying more RAM?

Comment: I want to know if there is a solution without having to buy more RAM. I will add this to my question, thanks.

Comment: Get a free account in a cloud provider (Google, AWS or Azure) and do it in the cloud for free

Comment: [Dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) is used for large files.

Comment: why do you need to manipulate all the csvs all at once? are you going to pre-process it and transform? because if so, you can just chunk it using the `chunksize` argument in `pd.read_csv`, get a portion of it, test the code for pre-processing and then iterating chunk by chunk. 

Otherwise, your other choice is to use `dask`, which will parallel process your data, if possible

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions! I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

To solve my problem, I created 7 cells (one for each data file). Within each cell I read the file, manipulated it, saved what I needed, then deleted everything:

```
import pandas as pd
import gc

df = pd.read_csv('Google drive path', compression = 'gzip')
filtered_df = df.query('my query condition here')
filtered_df.to_csv('new Google drive path', compression = 'gzip')

del df
del filtered_df

gc.collect()
```

After all 7 files, each about 500MB, for a total row-by-column size of 7,000,000 by 100, my RAM has stayed under 1MB.

Just using `del` didn't free up enough RAM. I had to use `gc.collect()` after in each cell.